iOS - Expandable View won't open when tapping on plugin card after application idle for a while
We developed a plugin card that opens an expandable view when the user taps on it (using banno-plugin-framework-bridge).
It works fine if the user taps the plugin card immediately after logging in. However, we’ve noticed a strange behavior on iOS: if the user leaves the Garden FI open with the plugin card still visible in the mobile viewport for around 2-3 minutes, and then taps the plugin card, a click-link post message is sent. But instead of opening the expandable view, Garden FI forces the plugin card to reload. After the reload, everything works as expected.
This issue does not occur on the Android version of the Garden FI app.
Is there a way to prevent this plugin card reload in this scenario?
We’ve observed that other plugin cards, like Credit Score, Messages, and Bill Pay, have a mechanism that refreshes their content automatically before the user interacts with them. How can we implement this behavior?

We haven't heard reports of that behavior. A few questions, if you could please update your question with: 1) Version of the iOS app you're using, 2) Operating system version, 3) Version of the Plugin Bridge, and ideally 4) video of the behavior?

@JaimeLopezJr. 1) App version 3.16.0, 2) iOS version 17.5.1, 3) Bridge version is the one on Banno github branch master (version 1.0.2 in package.json, 4) The behavior https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_RknGU-8_ZI8XwM1klpH94Y6YGu4eTGf/view , the short description: after application running in background or idle ~ 2 minutes, after login again, tapping on plugin will fire click-link event and the plugin reload after event is fired, if the event is not fired, the reload will not triggered.

Thanks for sharing the video. To help us troubleshoot better, if you could provide some reproducible code for us, either using the https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example or https://github.com/Banno/basic-plugin-example - we can try to dig into the root cause.

@Sam There is the sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hi7Yzvv8YJIRkHATkRux2Qe0um93OR_V/view . I just change the dynamic.ejs file as same with the screen recording above. Test scenario is just: Login, see the plugin loaded, lock phone, after 2~3 minutes, login again then tap on plugin card.

I was able to replicate your issue, and I think I solved it by monitoring the visibility and sending a refresh request if needed - https://gist.github.com/samuelcouch/9d1ca921274c0791466c9f78b60ca6d7 this may not be the best or most robust solution, but it is an example.

@Sam Is there any way to confirm that the host application is handling the 'refresh-request' event? When I lock the phone and log in after half an hour, the 'refresh-request' is sent as expected. However, after the 'click-link' event fires, the plugin unexpectedly reloads.

I'm not entirely sure. That sounds like it is related to the logic I added to your example and not an issue with the plugin-bridge.
